# Need a msol command like set-mailbox -emailaddresspolicyenabled for hybrid server

Tags: powershell, office365, hybrid

We have office 365 and a hybrid server. It is set to sync 1 way from hybrid to o365.

We are wanting to run

```
Set-mailbox  "$usertodisable@domain.com" -EmailAddressPolicyEnabled $true
```

on the hybrid server.

The problem is the hybrid server doesn't support/have the -mailbox commands. It has the -msol commands. I can not find an msol command that changes the emailaddresspolicyenabled. I also don't see a module to load for -mailbox.

We are running this command directly off the server itself. Any help would be great. Thank you and have a great day.

Comment: [Connect to Office365](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj984289(v=exchg.160).aspx) and run the command in the remote session

Comment: our office 365 account doesn't sync back down to hybrid (I am not in control of this option lol). I tried this and it never took effect on the hybrid. Our hybrid server is a local server.

Comment: Have you tried installing Exchange Management tools on the hybrid server?

Comment: I have not. I will have to get approval for this but I will try that. If that contains the -mailbox commands then this will work perfect. Thanks for the direction on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Set-RemoteMailbox](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607302(v=exchg.160).aspx) cmdlet to modify remote mailboxes. A remote mailbox is a mail user in Active Directory that's associated with a mailbox in the cloud-based service.

So what you are searching for seamed to be:

> Set-RemoteMailbox -Identity "$usertodisable@domain.com" -EmailAddressPolicyEnabled $True

Comment: Checked and that command is not available. Who ever set up the hybrid server must of not installed any of the exchange modules.

Comment: Make sure that your account has the "Mailbox Import Export" role, then try it again please.

Comment: This worked. Thank you so much. I don't have enough rep to 1up this but thanks for the help.